# ExtJs enabled/disabling fields

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

in ExtJs I have a combobox and several fields on the same form. I want the fields, which start out disabled, to become enabled based on selections in the combo box. In order to do that I have the following:

```
listeners: { change: {
                    fn: function (combo, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                        if (newValue == "amz") {
                            var amazonFields = this.up('panel').query('#amz1, #amz2, #amz3');
                            amazonFields[0].disabled = 'false';
                            amazonFields[1].disabled = 'false';
                            amazonFields[2].disabled = 'false';
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The code works as I expect it to, but the fields stay disabled, can anyone tell me why? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `disabled` property of the field is read-only.  To change its state you need to call the [`setDisabled`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-setDisabled) or [`disable`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-disable) methods.

Also, `'false'` is not the same as `false` in JavaScript.